# How to create a database with instances of tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, sqlite, schema

I am building a ruby on rails application and setting up my database. I have not worked with databases much in the past and I am running into a problem.

I created a table called 'Products', now I also want to have a table called 'Carts' which will house the ID of all the carts that exist for the store.

Where I am confused, is how to set up the actual cart.
Can I have a table called 'Cart' that stores a bunch of products and have multiple instances of it, each with there own ID?

Or can there only be one instance of every table?

How should I go about setting up having many carts all holding their own assortment of products?

Comment: In `carts` model define relation `has_many :products`, [The has_many Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table carts and a table cart_lines.

carts could these attributes:

```
number, user_id
```

and a table cart_lines with attributes:

```
cart_id, product_id, quantity....
```

Then you can set your Cart model:

```
has_many :cart_lines
belongs_to :user
```

CartLines model:

```
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to :product
```

Products model:

```
has_many :cart_lines
```

If you wish to fill the cart using nested form you add to Cart model:

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_lines, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: It was the 'has many' part I didn't realize existed. Thank you :)